# Functions that do not automatically inherit

Tags: c++, inheritance, operator-overloading

In c++ i read in bruce eckel that functions that do not automatically inherit are :

1. Constructors
2. Destructors
3. Operator = ( because it does the constructor like thing)

but this code says something else

```
#include<iostream>             
using namespace std;`                   

class A {
 public:
   A & operator= (A &a) {
    cout<<" base class assignment operator called ";
    return *this;
   }
};

class B: public A { };

int main()
{
  B a, b;
  a.A::operator=(b); //calling base class assignment operator function
                // using derived class
  a = b; // this also works
  //getchar();
  return 0;

}
```

Output : base class assignment operator called

please explain.

Comment: You are explicitly calling the function. Why the surprise?

Comment: He is surprised that both assignments call A::operator=() i guess. But since A is part of each B, the implicit assignment of B will call assignment of the sub-object A.

Comment: @akash The program should ouput `base class assignment operator called  base class assignment operator called`.

Comment: @akash if your question has been answered, consider to mark the correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, it is not correct to say that `operator =` is not inherited. The problem is that it is *hidden* by the implicitly-generated `operator =` for the derived class, so that (for instance), an assignment such as the one in the code below would be illegal:

```
A a;
B b;
b = a;
```

Since class `B` does not have any `operator =` accepting an `A`, but only an implicitly generated copy-assignment operator with the following signature:

```
B& operator = (B const&)
```

The situation is not different from the case of regular member functions in the derived class hiding member functions with the same name in the base class.

And as for regular member functions, you can have a `using` declaration in your class that makes the base class's `operator =` available:

```
class B: public A
{
public:
    using A::operator =;
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
};
```

This would make the assignment in the previous example compile.

Comment: but if i m not using it , writing simply a = b then? how does the base class version is called ? see the o/p

Comment: @akash: `a` and `b` are objects of type `B`. As I explained in my answer, `B` has an implicitly-generated `operator =`, so the expression `a = b` is valid. But that implicitly-generated operator *hides* the one from the base class, so if you would want to assign an object of type `A` to an object of type `B` by relying on that assignment operator, you would have troubles. I think my answer explains that

Comment: @AndyProwl I think op is just not aware of the fact that the implicit assignment operator of `B` will call the assignment operator for `A` for its sub-object of type `A`.

Answer (score 0):

According to http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/programming_books/thinking_in_c++/Chapter14_010.html , when you do not define a constructor, destructor or `=` operator for your class, it automatically creates a simple version of all three.

"In lieu of inheritance, these functions are synthesized by the compiler if you don’t create them yourself. (With constructors, you can’t create any constructors in order for the compiler to synthesize the default constructor and the copy-constructor.) The synthesized constructors use memberwise initialization and the synthesized operator= uses memberwise assignment."

Thus, B has a synthesized `=` operator automatically generated by the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

There is no inheritance of the operator=() of `A`. Instead, the base assignment operator is called from the derived class assignment operator, since the implicit assignment operator "simply" assigns all members and base classes.

(See Standard [Draft N3242] §12.8 for information on when the default copy or move assignment is implicitly generated and in which form.)

The standard (Draft N3242) says:

#### §12.8 / 29

> The implicitly-defined copy/move assignment operator for a non-union class X performs memberwise copy-/move assignment of its subobjects. **The direct base classes of X are assigned** first, in the order of their declaration in the base-specifier-list, and then the immediate non-static data members of X are assigned, in the order in which they were declared in the class definition.

There we get the assignment operator into place.

`X` is `B` and `direct base class` is `A`. So in the implicit assignment operator of `B`, it's sub-object of type `A` will be assigned using `A::operator=(...)`.

*Note: It is advantageous to provide your assignment operator parameter by const reference (or by value if using copy&swap).*